# Open with admin privileges from user privileged command prompt

Tags: cmd, privileges, administrator

Is there a way to open any program as you would with the standard right click "run as administrator" from the command prompt?

I know that this command

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

opens cmd as the administrator, but if the "hidden" admin account is not active:

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

it won't work, and if I want to activate it I need to have admin privileges and we're back to square one.

It doesn't matter if it asks for a password as long as it's from cmd. A "sudo" like on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already answered your own question. `RUNAS` is as equivalent to linux `su` more so than `sudo` that you are going to get.

At some point you're going to have to get admin rights to the windows box to begin with (i.e. activate the hidden admin account etc) because `sudo` in linux doesn't automatically work either. You have to be added to the `sodoers` list by someone with access to `/etc/sudoers` file. So there is some setup involved. All points back to being secure of unauthorized actions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your workstation is on a Windows domain, you could create a Domain Level account that has Admin privileges on all your workstations.

For example, create a Domain User called DOMAIN\WkstnAdmin. Add this WkstnAdmin user to the local administrators group on your workstations using a Domain Admin account (eg. DOMAIN\Administrator which should have full admin privileges) using a script or other remote method.

You can then use this WkstnAdmin account to run in an admin context as required, disable and enable the account as required and change the password as often as you wish.

In any event, I believe at the end of the day you will need to keep an Administrative account active on your PC (be it local or domain) in order to effectively manage your workstations.